# VSCode Debugging launch.json skipFiles exclude folder

Tags: node.js, vscode-debugger

what I am trying to do is to debug my application in vscode without stepping into the `node_modules` folder, except the ones which are written by myself. All of my own modules are prefixed with `simon-`


This is what I have:

```
"skipFiles": [
    "${workspaceFolder}/server/node_modules/**/*.js"
]
```

And I want to add something like:

```
"!${workspaceFolder}/server/node_modules/simon-*/**/*.js"
```

But this only works for legacy protocol, which only works on node 8 and below (I am using node 10). It seems there is no documentation on what syntax to use for the paths of the skipped files, or what to use instead of the `!`-symbol. Is it so obvious to everyone that nobody wrote it down? 


Thanks for the help. Appreciate.

Comment: See https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_8#_just-my-code-node-and-node2 it looks like your code should work.  Try reducing it to start with node_modules as the example shows in the link. (probably relative to your workspaceFolder anyway.

Comment: No, it does not work. In the debugging console it says that the line is skipped, because it is not supported for node 10